# Python unorderable types: NoneType() > int()

Tags: python

```
class Solution():
    def isHappy(self,n):
        t = n
        z = n       
        while t>0:
            t = self.cal(t)
            if t == 1:
                return True
            z = self.cal(self.cal(z))
            if z == 1:
                return True
            if t == z:
                return False

    def cal(self,n):
        x = n
        y = 0
        while x > 0: # unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
            y = y+(x%10)*(x%10)
            x = x/10



test = Solution()
result = test.isHappy(47)
print(result)
```

> I got error message in "while x > 0", "unorderable types: NoneType() >
>   int()". I change it to "while int(x)>0", but other error message,
>   "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'NoneType'". Any help, appreciate your time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is self-explanatory: the value of `n` passed to `cal()` becomes `None`, which can not be compared. Make sure to return an appropriate value at the end of the `cal()` method, that's where the `None` is coming from. Add something like this at the end of `cal()`:

```
return x # or `y`, depending on what you intend to do
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `cal` function should return something.

```
t = self.cal(t)
```

here you use the result of `cal`, but `cal` doesn't have a `return` statement, thus returning the default of `None`. Fix it by returning the correct value.